# How to make an Angled arrow style border in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How to make an Angled arrow-type border in PyQt QFrame? In My code, I Have two QLabels and respective frames. My aim is to make an arrow shape border on right side of every QFrame.For clear-cut idea, attach a sample picture.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Angle_Border(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Angle Border")

        self.lbl1 = QLabel("Python")
        self.lbl2 = QLabel("PyQt")

        self.frame1 = QFrame()
        self.frame1.setProperty("type","1")
        self.frame1.setFixedSize(200,50)
        self.frame1.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;color:white;"
                                  "font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size: 15pt;text-align: center;"
                                  "border-top-right-radius:25px solid ; border-bottom-right-radius:25px solid ;")
        self.frame2 = QFrame()
        self.frame2.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.frame2.setStyleSheet("background-color:blue;color:white;"
                                  "font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size: 15pt;text-align: center;"
                                  "border-top:1px solid transparent; border-bottom:1px solid  transparent;")
        self.frame_outer = QFrame()
        self.frame_outer.setFixedSize(800, 60)
        self.frame_outer.setStyleSheet("background-color:green;color:white;"
                                  "font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size: 15pt;text-align: center;")

        self.frame1_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.frame1)
        self.frame2_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.frame2)
        self.frame_outer_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_outer)
        self.frame_outer_layout.setContentsMargins(5,0,0,0)

        self.frame1_layout.addWidget(self.lbl1)
        self.frame2_layout.addWidget(self.lbl2)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.frame1)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.frame2)
        self.hbox.addStretch()
        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        # self.layout.addLayout(self.hbox)
        self.frame_outer_layout.addLayout(self.hbox)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.frame_outer)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Angle_Border()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Sample Picture**
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the OP didn't ask for user interaction (mouse or keyboard), a possible solution could use the existing features of Qt, specifically QSS (Qt Style Sheets).

While the <s>currently</s> previously accepted [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73090177/2001654) *does* follow that approach, it's not very effective, most importantly because it's basically "static", since it always requires knowing the color of the following item in order to define the "arrow" colors.
This not only forces the programmer to always consider the "sibling" items, but also makes extremely (and unnecessarily) complex the dynamic creation of such objects.

The solution is to always (partially) "redo" the layout and update the stylesheets with the necessary values, which consider the current size (which shouldn't be hardcoded), the *following* item (if any) and carefully using the layout properties and "spacer" stylesheets based on the contents.

The following code uses a more abstract, dynamic approach, with basic functions that allow adding/insertion and removal of items. It still uses a similar QSS method, but, with almost the same "line count", it provides a simpler and much more intuitive approach, allowing item creation, deletion and modification with single function calls that are much easier to use.

A further benefit of this approach is that implementing "reverse" arrows is quite easy, and doesn't break the logic of the item creation.

Considering all the above, you can create an *actual* class that just needs basic calls such as `addItem()` or `removeItem()`.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class ArrowMenu(QWidget):
    vMargin = -1
    hMargin = -1
    def __init__(self, items=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.addStretch()
        self.items = []
        if isinstance(items, dict):
            self.addItems(items.items())
        elif items is not None:
            self.addItems(items)

    def addItems(self, items):
        for item in items:
            if isinstance(item, str):
                self.addItem(item)
            else:
                self.addItem(*item)

    def addItem(self, text, background=None):
        self.insertItem(len(self.items), text, background)

    def insertItem(self, index, text, background=None):
        label = QLabel(text)
        if background is None:
            background = self.palette().window().color()
            background.setAlpha(0)
        else:
            background = QColor(background)

        # human eyes perceive "brightness" in different ways, let's compute
        # that value in order to decide a color that has sufficient contrast
        # with the background; see https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/10412
        r, g, b, a = background.getRgbF()
        brightness = r * .3 + g * .59 + b * .11
        foreground = 'black' if brightness >= .5 else 'white'

        label.setStyleSheet('color: {}; background: {};'.format(
            foreground, background.name(background.HexArgb)))

        layout = self.layout()
        if index < len(self.items):
            i = 0
            for _label, _spacer, _ in self.items:
                if i == index:
                    i += 1
                layout.insertWidget(i * 2, _label)
                layout.insertWidget(i * 2 + 1, _spacer)
                i += 1

        layout.insertWidget(index * 2, label)
        spacer = QWidget(objectName='menuArrow')
        layout.insertWidget(index * 2 + 1, spacer)
        self.items.insert(index, (label, spacer, background))
        self.updateItems()

    def removeItem(self, index):
        label, spacer, background = self.items.pop(index)
        label.deleteLater()
        spacer.deleteLater()
        layout = self.layout()
        for i, (label, spacer, _) in enumerate(self.items):
            layout.insertWidget(i * 2, label)
            layout.insertWidget(i * 2 + 1, spacer)
        self.updateItems()
        self.updateGeometry()

    def updateItems(self):
        if not self.items:
            return

        size = self.fontMetrics().height()
        if self.vMargin < 0:
            vSize = size * 2
        else:
            vSize = size + self.vMargin * 2
        spacing = vSize / 2
        self.setMinimumHeight(vSize)
        if self.hMargin >= 0:
            labelMargin = self.hMargin * 2
        else:
            labelMargin = size // 2

        it = iter(self.items)
        prevBackground = prevSpacer = None
        while True:
            try:
                label, spacer, background = next(it)
                label.setContentsMargins(labelMargin, 0, labelMargin, 0)
                spacer.setFixedWidth(spacing)

            except StopIteration:
                background = QColor()
                break

            finally:
                if prevBackground:
                    if background.isValid():
                        cssBackground = background.name(QColor.HexArgb)
                    else:
                        cssBackground = 'none'
                    if prevBackground.alpha():
                        prevBackground = prevBackground.name(QColor.HexArgb)
                    else:
                        mid = QColor(prevBackground)
                        mid.setAlphaF(.5)
                        prevBackground = '''
                            qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
                            stop:0 {}, stop:1 {})
                        '''.format(
                            prevBackground.name(QColor.HexArgb), 
                            mid.name(QColor.HexArgb), 
                            )
                    prevSpacer.setStyleSheet('''
                        ArrowMenu > .QWidget#menuArrow {{
                            background: transparent;
                            border-top: {size}px solid {background};
                            border-bottom: {size}px solid {background};
                            border-left: {spacing}px solid {prevBackground};
                        }}
                    '''.format(
                            size=self.height() // 2, 
                            spacing=spacing, 
                            prevBackground=prevBackground, 
                            background=cssBackground
                    ))

                prevBackground = background
                prevSpacer = spacer

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.updateItems()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    items = (
            ('Python', 'green'), 
            ('Will delete', 'chocolate'), 
            ('PyQt5', 'red'), 
            ('Java', 'blue'), 
            ('ASP.Net', 'yellow'), 
        )
    ex = ArrowMenu(items)
    ex.show()
    QTimer.singleShot(2000, lambda: ex.addItem('New item', 'aqua'))
    QTimer.singleShot(5000, lambda: ex.removeItem(1))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is the result:

[image: screenshot of the example]

Answer (score 5):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QHBoxLayout,QLabel,QFrame,QApplication,QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MyFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,base_color,top_color,width,edge,text,text_color):
        super().__init__()
        self.base_color = base_color
        self.top_color = top_color
        self.width = width
        self.edge = edge
        self.text = text
        self.text_color = text_color

        self.lbl = QLabel()
        self.lbl.setText(self.text)
        self.lbl.setFixedHeight(self.width*2)
        self.lbl.setMinimumWidth((QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)+100)
        self.lbl.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.lbl.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.lbl.setStyleSheet(f"QLabel"
                               f"{{background-color: {self.base_color};"
                               f"color:{self.text_color};"
                               f"font-family:Trebuchet MS;"
                               f"font-size: 15pt;}}")
        self.frame_triangle = QFrame()
        self.frame_triangle.setFixedSize(self.width, self.width * 2)
        self.frame_triangle.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
    
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)

        if self.edge == "right":
            self.border = "border-left"
            self.hbox.addWidget(self.lbl)
            self.hbox.addWidget(self.frame_triangle)
        elif self.edge == "left":
            self.border = "border-right"
            self.hbox.addWidget(self.frame_triangle)
            self.hbox.addWidget(self.lbl)
        elif self.edge == "none":
            self.border = "border-right"
            self.hbox.addWidget(self.lbl)
            self.lbl.setMinimumWidth((QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding) + 150)

        self.frame_triangle.setStyleSheet(f"QFrame"
                       f"{{background-color: {self.base_color};"
                       f"border-top:100px solid {self.top_color};"
                       f"{self.border}:100px solid {self.base_color};"
                       f"border-bottom:100px solid {self.top_color};"
                       f"}}")

class Main_Frame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Angled Frame")
        triangle_size = 50
        self.frame1 = MyFrame("lightgrey","green",triangle_size,"right","","lightgrey")
        self.frame2 = MyFrame("green","red",triangle_size,"right","Python","white")
        self.frame3 = MyFrame("red","blue",triangle_size,"right","PyQt5","white")
        self.frame4 = MyFrame("blue","yellow",triangle_size,"right","Java","white")
        self.frame5 = MyFrame("yellow","lightgrey",triangle_size,"right","ASP.Net","black")

        self.frame_overall = QFrame()
        self.frame_overall.setStyleSheet("background-color:lightgrey;")
        self.frame_overall.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum,QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        self.frame_overall_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_overall)
        self.frame_overall_layout.setSpacing(0)

        # self.frame_overall_layout.addWidget(self.frame1)
        self.frame_overall_layout.addWidget(self.frame2)
        self.frame_overall_layout.addWidget(self.frame3)
        self.frame_overall_layout.addWidget(self.frame4)
        self.frame_overall_layout.addWidget(self.frame5)

        self.vbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        self.vbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.vbox.addStretch()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.frame_overall)
        self.vbox.addStretch()
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main_Frame()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer! Perhaps you can also post your answer under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29796256/9758790). This avoid overloading the `paintEvent`

Comment: @hellohawaii That question clearly asks for *buttons*, while this answer doesn't provide any of that. In fact, I'm considering to remove my answer here and post it there instead, as I initially thought that the OP asked for user interaction, but since they accepted their own answer, I was clearly wrong.

Comment: @Bala As written above, I mistakenly thought that you also needed user interaction, but now it seems clear that it's not your case. If you confirm that, I'll update my answer accordingly (or just post another one and remove the current one, since it's unrelated).

Comment: @Bala Also, those `(QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding) + ...` are just **wrong**. Those are *enum flags*, they are not actual pixel values that could be used for sizes. Also, [`width()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#width-prop) is a dynamic property of all QWidgets, and overwriting it is discouraged, ***especially*** when using widgets that deal with sizes for which you *may* need to access those properties.

Comment: @musicamante :  I really expect your pythonic way of approach/ solution.  and please don't remove the current solution provided by you.

Comment: @musicamante, Your way of approach to solving the problem is an entirely different way,  and very interesting one.   So pls don't delete it. It's very useful to me in some other situations.

Comment: @musicamante, As a leaner and as of my knowledge, I try my level best.  So expect your valuable suggestions and corrections and also expect to post a rectified code or solve the problem in your own interesting pythonic way. :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29847772/9758790) can anwser your question. However, I adopt a python version for you.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPainter, QPen, QPainterPath, QBrush

class Angle_Border(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, firstButtonX, firstButtonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, triangleWidth, labels, colors):
        super().__init__()
        self.firstButtonX = firstButtonX
        self.firstButtonY = firstButtonY
        self.buttonWidth = buttonWidth
        self.buttonHeight = buttonHeight
        self.triangleWidth = triangleWidth
        self.labels = labels
        self.colors = colors

        self.button_lists = []
        for i, text_i in enumerate(self.labels):
            button_i = QPushButton(text_i, self)
            self.button_lists.append(button_i)
            button_i.setGeometry(self.firstButtonX + (self.buttonWidth+self.triangleWidth)*i, self.firstButtonY,
                                 self.buttonWidth, self.buttonHeight)
            button_i.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;border-style: outset;border-width: 0px;" % (QColor(self.colors[i]).name()))
            # button_i.setStyleSheet("border-style: outset;border-width: 0px;")

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        for i, button_i in enumerate(self.button_lists):
            x = button_i.pos().x()
            y = button_i.pos().y()
            w = button_i.width()
            h = button_i.height()

            r = QRect(x+w, y, self.triangleWidth, h)

            #
            #   _____p1
            #  |      \ p3
            #  |_____ /
            #        p2
            point3X = x + w + self.triangleWidth
            point3Y = y + h/2
            point1X = x + w
            point1Y = y
            point2X = x + w
            point2Y = y + h

            path = QPainterPath()
            path.moveTo(point1X, point1Y)
            path.lineTo(point2X, point2Y)
            path.lineTo(point3X, point3Y)

            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.NoPen))
            if i != len(self.button_lists) - 1:
                painter.fillRect(r, QBrush(self.colors[i+1]))
            painter.fillPath(path, QBrush(self.colors[i]))

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    firstButtonX = 0
    firstButtonY = 0
    buttonWidth = 50
    buttonHeight = 30
    triangleWidth = 30
    labels = ["step1", "step2", "step3"]
    colors = [Qt.red, Qt.blue, Qt.yellow]

    ex = Angle_Border(firstButtonX, firstButtonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, triangleWidth, labels, colors)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use QTabBar and override its paint event.

For better display of the last tab, we also override the size hint functions in order to have enough space to show the last arrow without clipping it or drawing over the text.

```py
class ArrowTabBar(QTabBar):
    def sizeHint(self):
        hint = super().sizeHint()
        if self.count():
            hint.setWidth(hint.width() + hint.height() * .2)
        return hint

    def minimumTabSizeHint(self, index):
        hint = super().minimumTabSizeHint(index)
        if index == self.count() - 1:
            hint.setWidth(hint.width() + hint.height() * .2)
        return hint

    def tabSizeHint(self, index):
        hint = super().tabSizeHint(index)
        if index == self.count() - 1:
            hint.setWidth(hint.width() + hint.height() * .2)
        return hint

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        count = self.count()
        if not count:
            return

        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(qp.Antialiasing)
        bottom = self.height()
        midY = bottom // 2
        midX = midY / 2.5
        bottom -= 1
        palette = self.palette()
        textColor = palette.windowText().color()
        normal = palette.mid()
        current = palette.dark()

        for i in range(count):
            rect = self.tabRect(i)
            path = QPainterPath()
            x = rect.x()
            right = rect.right()
            if i:
                path.moveTo(x - midX, bottom)
                path.lineTo(x + midX, midY)
                path.lineTo(x - midX, 0)
            else:
                path.moveTo(x, bottom)
                path.lineTo(x, 0)
            path.lineTo(right - midX, 0)
            path.lineTo(right + midX, midY)
            path.lineTo(right - midX, bottom)
            if i == self.currentIndex():
                qp.setBrush(current)
            else:
                qp.setBrush(normal)
            qp.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
            qp.drawPath(path)
            qp.setPen(textColor)
            qp.drawText(rect, Qt.AlignCenter|Qt.TextShowMnemonic, 
                self.tabText(i))


app = QApplication([])
panel = ArrowTabBar()
for i in range(5):
    panel.addTab('Item {}'.format(i + 1))
panel.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: On my arch linux system (sip-6.6.2, pyqt-5.15.7), this raises a type-error due to the use of floats in the size-hint methods. After fixing that, I see significant clipping of the rightmost item. It also seems weird that the tabs don't have a fixed height. After resizing vertically, clicking in certain areas sometimes results in the wrong tab being highlighted, and the behaviour of the scroll buttons can be somewhat flaky. (PS: it would also be nice if you included the imports in your example and added a screenshot - sorry to be so critical ;-).

Comment: @ekhumoro You're right, I thought about the vertical size issue but didn't want to include it nor limit the size (I should probably implement it or at least add a warning). And, yes, I should be more careful with types, but it seems strange that you can see clipping because of that. I'll do some more tests (especially for the wheel issue, as I didn't notice anything wrong) and update the answer. Thank you, and don't be sorry, those are very useful critics! :-)

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest fixing the types *caused* the clipping - just that after getting the example to run, I see clipping. Also, by scroll buttons, I mean the overflow buttons that appear at the end of the tab-bar, not the mouse wheel. (PS: I tried running the example with fusion rather than my usual widget-style, and it still clips about 6 pixels).

Comment: @ekhumoro I found out what was the source of the issue and fixed my code (I changed the way the arrows are positioned), but now I'm realizing that the OP doesn't seem interested in mouse interaction, and the purpose is probably purely aesthetic. I'm waiting for a reply from the OP on their own answer and eventually decide to change/delete this answer and post it to the other related post.

Comment: @musicamante You answer looks very useful and don't delete it :-) Perhaps you can post another question considering mouse interaction and post your answer there. Or perhaps you can just insert your new version of solution before your old version.

Comment: @hellohawaii I didn't mean that my answer wasn't useful, but it seems like the OP wasn't looking for that kind of implementation, so it would be more appropriate for the question you originally linked in your own answer. I originally considered the stylesheet approach the OP used on their answer, but I decided to go for another solution; after rethinking I realized that the QSS method *is* a viable option (but certainly not like that, as it's conceptually *too* static and makes any modification unnecessarily complex); I'm in the process of providing a *separate* answer for that.